# compactness and maximal elements

Tags: reference-request, compactness, order-theory

Let $C$ be a nonempty compact subset of $R^n$, with a certain partial order defined on it. I am trying to prove that $C$ contains a maximal element.

My idea is: start with a certain element of $C$. If it is not maximal,  replace it with a larger element, and so on. This process results in a sequence of elements in $C$. Because of compactness, this sequence has a subsequence that converges to an element in $C$. This limit, $l$, must be a maximal element.

Is this true? I am particularly unsure about the last statement - is this true that the limit must be a maximal element?

ADDITION: If the claim is not true, what condition can be added in order to make it true?

A second question is: if this theorem (possibly with an additional condition) is indeed true, is it a well-known fact that I can cite in a paper without having to prove it?

Comment: I find this hard to believe. Is there some continuity condition on the partial order? As stated, there is no connection to the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Why would the limit be maximal?

Comment: $C=[0,1] \times \mathbb{R}$ is a nonempty compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The cardinality of $C$ equals the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. Use any bijection $C \leftrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ together with the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$ to define an order on $C$. There is no maximal element.

Comment: @LeeMosher: your $C$ is not compact.

Comment: To fix the example proposed by @LeeMosher, we could use the natural ordering on $(0,1)$ and assign any compatible ordering to $\{0,1\}$ (with neither being maximal). Then the resulting ordering on the compact set $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ has no maximal elements.

Comment: @user153841 what exactly do you mean by "continuity condition on the partial order"? Perhaps this is the part I have been missing here.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: I mean there must be some extra information about the partial order that connects it to the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Otherwise there's nothing you can deduce about whether or not the limit of a (ascending, with respect to order) sequence is maximal. I'll post an answer to be more clear.

Comment: I mistyped, I meant $C = [0,1] \times {0}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counterexample:** Consider the compact subset $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Define the usual order on $[0,1) \subset [0,1]$, and extend to $[0,1]$ by defining $ 1 \leq x$ for all $x \in [0,1)$.

A couple of observations: (1) Given an ascending sequence approaching $1$, its limit (i.e. 1) is *not* maximal. (2) We could use your approach to find an ascending sequence that has limit $1/2$, say $x_n= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}$. But $\frac{1}{2}$ is clearly not maximal in $[0,1]$, even with the *usual* ordering.

**How to salvage it:** Since you want to use the compactness of the set, it makes sense to at least have the partial order respect limits. That is, if $x_n \leq x_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and $x_n \to a$, then $x_n \leq a$ for all $n$.

Comment: Is this salvation sufficient? As you explain, even with the usual ordering it is possible to have a sequence that converges to an element in $C$ which is not maximal. So my proof is probably incorrect. How can I correct it?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: The condition that the partial order respects limits is *definitely* not sufficient. Honestly, I have no idea what conditions would be sufficient. However, I don't think that this is necessarily what you need if this question pertains to your earlier post about Pareto-efficient cake cutting. See my response there.